# Right click to open React Link in new tab is throwing 404 Not Found error

Tags: react-router-dom, react-link

I am using react-router-dom Link to navigate to a page and the code is as below:

```
<Link to={'/xyz/login'}>Click here to Login</Link>
```

This works fine when the application is running on my local machine. But on server, when I try to right click and open the link in new tab, **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found** message is displayed.

Any thoughts on the issue is appreciated.

Comment: happens to me just now while deploying to netlify. have you found any solution?